# How to remove text between two specified strings (start and stop) using Python?

Tags: python

I have a series of texts in a file.txt structured like so :

```
// text 1
A Title always the same for all the texts
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Maecenas mollis libero eget turpis blandit, non efficitur ipsum sodales.

A Subtitle always the same for all the texts
A text that I want to remove.

// text 2
A Title always the same for all the texts
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Maecenas mollis libero eget turpis blandit, non efficitur ipsum sodales.

A Subtitle always the same for all the texts
Another text that I want to remove.
```

I want to remove the text below the subtitle and above the title, ie, in my above example : "*A text that I want to remove*" and "*Another text I want to remove*". I know these texts are always between "*A Subtitle always the same for all the texts*" and "*A Title always the same for all the texts*"

Comment: Did you try *anything*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy with slicing and `string.index()`. The index method just returns the index where it first finds the string you're passing. So you can use it to find where your headings start and stop. Unlike the similar `find()` method, this will return an error if your file doesn't contain the necessary string so you'll know what's happened, while `find` will just return -1 and continue even though that index will be useless.

String slicing is what allows you to get a substring of a string, ie:

```
text = "Hello"
text[2:4]
>>> 'll'
```

Giving it the indices of where to start and stop will return the string between those two locations. With those combined you can get the substring like this:

```
text = '''Your string goes here'''
start = "A Subtitle always the sam for all the texts"
stop = "A Title always the same for all the texts"
text = text[text.index(start) : text.index(stop) + len(stop)]
```

(adding `len(stop)` makes sure the string still includes the subheading, but if you remove it the subheading will no longer be retained)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> text = '''
... A Title always the same for all the texts
... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
... Maecenas mollis libero eget turpis blandit, non efficitur ipsum sodales.
...
... A Subtitle always the same for all the texts
... A text that I want to remove.
... '''
>>> start = 'A Subtitle always the same for all the texts'
>>> stop = 'A Title always the same for all the texts'
>>> text.split(start, 1)[1].split(stop, 1)[0]
'\nA text that I want to remove.\n'
```